# Loop x86 Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm trying to write a program for my Architecture class that will loop through the chars of a string, but my loop isn't working and I'm not sure why. It keeps giving me Error: too many memory references for `mov'.

```
    mov $10,AL
    top:
    ~~STUFF~~
    dec AL
    jnz top

    next:
```

Yes I know questions like this are all over the internet. I just keep getting the same errors with everything I try and I don't have all the time in the world left. I moved 10 into the AL registry, I set top as my jump return point, and I used jnz which is jump if not equal to zero right? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which assembler are you using? In some assemblers (Intel versus AT&T style), the destination argument is first, so `mov $10, AL` might be attempting to move `AL` to a constant, which is invalid.

Comment: I'm using AT&T Style I believe

Comment: "and I don't have all the time in the world left". This is very rude of you to say. Why do you assume that **we** do?

Answer (score 2):

Supposing that this assembly is in AT&T syntax, `mov $10,AL` means "move the immediate `10` into the memory location specified by the label `AL`". Same goes for `dec AL`, but there's another problem : you're not specifying the size of the operand, and the assembler has no way of knowing whether `AL` points to a byte, a word, a doubleword, or a quadword (though some HLAs do that, AFAIK). Therefore, you need to specify the size of the operand. In AT&T syntax, this is done by appending a suffix to the instruction mnemonic : `b` for byte, `w` for word, `d` for doubleword, and `q` for quadword.

Registers, on the other hand, are prefixed with the `%` sign in AT&T syntax : therefore, if you wanted to use the `al` register for your instructions, you should have written `mov $10, %al` and `dec %al`. Do notice how you don't need the operand size suffixes in these cases : the assembler can work them out based on the size of the register you want to use. However, I've always encouraged appending the suffix regardless of that : therefore, write `movb $10, %al` and `decb %al` and you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure your error is with the code you've shown:
On x86, `MOV` can't move anything directly from memory to memory, you have to store the data in a register in between. The Error you get seems to indicate you tried `MOV MEM, MEM` somewhere in your code.